# jquery timer vs javascript timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

which timer is better for use in term of performance ? the Jquery Timer or The Javascript Timer.

the page that has the timer doesnt have any Jquery code.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery is written in Javascript. jQuery *is* Javascript. Please work out the implications yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing the full JQuery library on a page which is only using its timer sounds like overkill - you can probably save on bandwidth and not use it.